# How to create an empty folder when a file with the folder's name already exists?

Tags: c#, file, io, path, directory

I am sure there is something simple that I am overlooking here but I have never ran into this problem before and I cannot seam to find the cause of the problem.

This an example of the root directory on my hard-drive:

```
C:\Folder-1          ( this is a folder )
C:\Folder-2          ( this is a folder )
C:\somename          ( this is a file with no extension )
c:\somename.txt      ( this is a file with an extension )
```

The code I want to use to create a new folder is this method:

```
static void Main( string[] args )
{
    try
    {
        // try to create a folder in a directory 
        // where a file with the same name exsists
        createDirectory( "c:\somename" );
    }
    catch
    {
       // this catches an exception "Cannot create directory, because it already exsist
    }
}

private static void createDirectory(string filePath)
      {
         string directoryPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(filePath);

         // if the directory path does not exsists then create it
         if (!Directory.Exists(directoryPath))
         {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(directoryPath );
         }
      }
```

Does anyone see what is wrong here?  Please help and thank you!

Comment: Delete the file first. Inside any given folder, only **one item** (file or folder) with any given name can exist. You **cannot** have a file and a folder both with the same name

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't.

You can't have two file system entries with the same name.

So either:

1. Delete the file, then reuse the old name for the new directory
2. Rename the file, then reuse the old name for the new directory
3. Create the directory with a different name

Note that NTFS has its roots in POSIX, and POSIX allows multiple file system entries that differ by case, because the file system is case sensitive regarding object names. NTFS inherited this trait, but Win32 will block you from doing this. Using Win32 it is thus not possible to create a file called `X` together with a file called `x` in the same directory, but using lower level system calls it may be possible.

See https://superuser.com/questions/364057/why-is-ntfs-case-sensitive for more information on this topic.

However, identical names for multiple file system entries is not allowed and never has been.

Comment: This is backed by the fact that Windows tells you it cannot be done if you try to do it via GUI

Comment: I'd like to have a link to some system documentation that once and for all documents that this is the rule, but I can't find it. If anyone has a good link for this information, please add a comment, or edit the answer.

Comment: You can't. It is not possible. According to POSIX rules you can have two file system entries with the "same name" if they only differ by casing, but due to the large amount of problems this causes with software that isn't designed to cope with this, it has been disabled. Either way, you can not have two file system entries with identical names, that has never been possible. There's not one list for directories and one for files, it's the same list, and the name in that list has to be unique. So no, you really cannot do this.

Comment: For some information on casing, see http://superuser.com/questions/364057/why-is-ntfs-case-sensitive - It appears the Win32 api (and thus what almost all software uses) does not allow filenames that only differ by case, but it may be possible using lower level system calls. However, again, multiple entries with identical names have never been allowed and is 100% not possible.